# How to get only rows with duplicate id with specific values of a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with these two columns

```
+------+------+
|id    |type  |
+------+------+
|1     |A     |
+------+------+
|1     |B     |
+------+------+
|2     |B     |
+------+------+
|3     |A     |
+------+------+
|3     |B     |
+------+------+
|3     |C     |
+------+------+
|4     |A     |
+------+------+
|4     |A     |
+------+------+
```

and I want to get rows only with duplicate id that has value A and B for Type column

It should look something like this:

```
+------+------+
|id    |type  |
+------+------+
|1     |A     |
+------+------+
|1     |B     |
+------+------+
|3     |A     |
+------+------+
|3     |B     |
+------+------+
```

I tried the query below which does print out rows with only the duplicate ids but wasn't able to get rows with value A and B only

```
select id, type from table s1
where (select count(id) from table s2 where s2.id = s1.id and type in ('A', 'B')) > 1 
group by id, type
order by id
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name wasn't sure why this was marked as duplicate. the similar question doesn't really solve this as i only want rows with duplicate ids. the other solution will get the rows with value a and b but it will get for the non duplicate id as well. i cant seem to combine the query above (to get rows with duplicate id) and the solution that is marked similar which is why this question was posted.

Comment: @horse_with_no_name thanks for re-opening. appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `count` analytical function as follows:

```
select id, type from
(select id, type, count(distinct type) over (partition by id) as cnt
  from t where type in ('A','B')) t
where cnt = 2
```

You can also use `EXISTS` as follows:

```
select id, type from your_table  t 
 where type in ('A','B')
   and exists (select 1 from your_table tt
                where t.id = tt.id 
                  and tt.type in ('A','B')
                  and tt.type <> t.type)
```

Comment: can i ask what does the cnt = 2 indicates?

Comment: We have taken two types in our query (`where type in ('A','B')`) and then counted the distinct types against each ID. If count is 2 then it means it has both A and B against Id

Comment: aa okay. got it. thanks. appreciate your help

Comment: seems like postgres doesn't allow the distinct after count. giving this error ERROR: DISTINCT is not implemented for window functions